# How to access salesforce1 in desktop

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-experience

When I add one\one.app to my lightning experience url it still remains in LEX not navigate to salesforce1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable mobile mode in your chrome browser by pressing F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I

[image]

Comment: Its been already enabled, still it shows only LEX not salesforce1.

Comment: have you refreshed the page after opening with /one/one.app

Comment: Thanks Himanshu, now I am able to access salesforce1 after page got refreshed.

Comment: awesome... that is what i said you need to refresh page :)

Comment: If access same in mobile, what I will get actually, is it LEX or salesforce1.

Comment: automatically you will get salesforce1